# I would like to know if I use "in" or "on"

Tags: prepositions

I would like to know if "in" is okay to use on the below sentence

Please notify me when your service **in** this matter has been concluded so we may close our file.

Comment: 'involvement in this matter' (or why not just 'involvement'?)

Comment: Can you give some more context explanation? Neither of these sound particularly natural--who is doing the service and what does it consist of?